# If $B \subsetneq A$ and $ f : A \rightarrow B $ is injective, then $ f[B] \subsetneq B $

Tags: discrete-mathematics, functions, elementary-set-theory

**Problem**: Let $ A,B $ be sets such that if $B \subsetneq A$ and $ f : A \rightarrow B $ is injective, then $ f[B] \subsetneq B $.

**Attempt:** Suppose $B \subsetneq A$ and $ f \in A \rightarrow B $ is injective. Let $ y  $ be arbitrary. Suppose $ y \in f[B] $. Hence there exists $ h \in B $ ( since $ f[B] = \{ f(h) | h\in B \}  $ ) s.t. $ f(h) = y \in B.  $ Hence $ y \in B $. Since $ y $ was arbitrary we showed $ f[B] \subseteq B $.
Now we'll show $ B \nsubseteq f[B]$ ( this will prove $ f[B] \neq B  $ ). [ I tried supposing $ B \subseteq f[B]$ and to reach a contradicition but I wasn't able to show this ].

**Difficulty:** Naively looking at my attempt, there are several things to be noted: I'm not using the assumption that $ f $ is injective, in addition, I'm not refering to the fact that $B \subsetneq A$ and so my attempt just feels wrong like I've neglected important details but not aware how exactly refer to them. Can you please give me a guidance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose $B \subseteq f(B)$. Take any $a \in A$. Then $f(a) \in B \subseteq f(B)$ so we can write $f(a)=f(b)$ for some $b \in B$. Since $f$ is injective this gives $a =b$ so $a \in B$. We have proved that $A \subseteq B$ which is a contradiction. [ It is given that $B \subseteq A$ but $B \neq A$].

Comment: More elegantly, you proved the contrapositive indeed :)

Comment: @drhab I don't see any mistake in the question or in my answer.